# TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

as per the title error , I am trying many times to solve this error but didn't find the solution until now
below is my full code, appreciate your attempt to find the reason of the error
you will find the details of error in this link:
[error details](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oQPPhxXkjNtdtThaUhgB8TUISpu_iNy_/view?usp=sharing)

please note that same code taking from a course in youtube which is working in the video with out any problem

Flaskblog.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html:

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

about.html:

```
 {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>About Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 5rem;
  }
  
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #444444;
  }
  
  .bg-steel {
    background-color: #5f788a;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #cbd5db;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .content-section {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .article-title {
    color: #444444;
  }
  
  a.article-title:hover {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .article-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
  
  .article-img {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  
  .article-metadata {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
  }
  
  .article-metadata a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .article-svg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  .account-img {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  
  .account-heading {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
```

Comment: the error as posted in the screenshot doesn't look like it's coming from the same home.html you've posted.   The error states that ```{{% if title %}}``` is invalid, but I don't see that line in your home.html or layout.html

Answer (score 1):

In your about.html you write...

```
{% endblock conten %}
```

You forgot the t at the end of content.

**Update**
Have a look at the template syntax of Jinja. In order to close the `block`tag, you just write `endblock`, not `endblock content`.

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/

Comment: yes thanks but i forget this here not in my computer and still it does not work and give same error

Comment: Please update your question with your current code and error message

Comment: updated and still give me same error, your trying to help is appreciated

Comment: I just copy pasted all your code on my machine, started Flask, and it works :-) No more syntax errors!

Comment: You did not update the error - it is still the old document from Aug 26th - the error contains something like "{{% if title %}}" - which is not in the code you show us.

Comment: yes because still i have same error, this statement :{{% if title %}} in layout.html file,anyhow, i update the link, check this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TfWm5KTc6XZRSDiKxeFiE5QwBY7SrHDS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also the code checked by one of my college and its working properly, do you think some thing shall be installed or upgrade in my computer ??

Comment: it is working now, i only restart my computer and re-run the code again

Answer (score 0):

File "C:\Users\dell\flask_blog\templates\home.html", line 4, in 
{{% if title %}}

In your `home.html` template you have invalid statement, it's either `{{ something }}` or `{% something %}` but you have mixed them into `{{% something %}}`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as you see in the code in my post, the code does not include in this mistake